# contentComponents is not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to to show sidebarscreen's profile picture and name in drawernavigation screen(MainScreen) by importing sidebarescreen in MainScreen but no content of Sidebar Screen is showing in MainScreen

here is My SidebarScreen

```
import React from 'react'
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,ScrollView,ImageBackground,Image} from 'react-native'
import {DrawerNavigationItems} from 'react-navigation-drawer'
// import MainScreen from './MainScreen'
import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons'

export default SidebarScreen = props =>{
    <ScrollView style={{marginTop:60}}>
        <ImageBackground
        source = {require("../../assets/screenback.jpg")}
        style={{width:undefined,padding:16,paddingTop:48}}
        >
        <Image source={require("../../assets/profile.png")} style={styles.profile} />
        <Text style={styles.name}>Satya Jeet</Text>

        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Text style={styles.follower}>734 Followers</Text>
        <Ionicons name= "md-people" size={16} color="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)"/>
        </View>
        </ImageBackground>
        <View style={styles.container}>

        </View>
    </ScrollView>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container:{
        flex:1,
    },
    profile:{
        width:80,
        height:80,
        borderRadius: 40,
        borderWidth: 3,
        borderColor: '#fff'
    },
    name:{
        color:"#fff",
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: '800',
        marginVertical: 8 
    },
    followers:{
        color:"rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
        fontSize: 13,
        marginRight: 4
    }

})
```

and here is my MainScreen

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation-drawer'
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'
// import SidebarScreen from './SidebarScreen'
import {Feather} from '@expo/vector-icons'

import {
    ProfileScreen,
    MessageScreen,
    ActivityScreen,
    ListScreen,
    ReportScreen,
    StatisticScreen,
    SignOutScreen,
} from "./Index"

import SidebarScreen from './SidebarScreen'

class MainScreen extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <MyApp/>
    )
  }
}
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({

    ProfileScreen:{
        screen: ProfileScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            title:"Profile",
            drawerIcon:({tintColor})=><Feather name="user" size={16} color={tintColor} />
        }
    },
    MessageScreen:{
        screen: MessageScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            title:"Message",
            drawerIcon:({tintColor})=><Feather name="message-square" size={16} color={tintColor} />
        }
    },
    ActivityScreen:{
        screen: ActivityScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            title:"Activity",
            drawerIcon:({tintColor})=><Feather name="activity" size={16} color={tintColor} />
        }
    },
    ListScreen:{
        screen: ListScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            title:"List",
            drawerIcon:({tintColor})=><Feather name="list" size={16} color={tintColor} />
        }
    },
    ReportScreen:{
        screen: ReportScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            title:"Report",
            drawerIcon:({tintColor})=><Feather name="trending-up" size={16} color={tintColor} />
        }
    },
    StatisticScreen:{
        screen: StatisticScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            title:"Statistic",
            drawerIcon:({tintColor})=><Feather name="bar-chart" size={16} color={tintColor} />
        }
    },
    SignOutScreen:{
        screen: SignOutScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            title:"SignOut",
            drawerIcon:({tintColor})=><Feather name="log-out" size={16} color={tintColor} />
        }
    },
},

  {
    contentComponents:SidebarScreen,

    // drawerWidth:Dimensions.get('window').width = 0.80,
    hideStatusBar: true,
    contentOptions:{
        activeBackgroundColor:"rgba(212,118,207,0.2)",
        activeTintColor:"#531158",
        itemsContainerStyle:{
            marginTop:16,
            marginHorizontal:8
        }
    }
  }

);

const MyApp = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);


export default MainScreen;

// export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```

here in MainScreen no content of SidebarScreen is showing even though I have added it in contentComponents

Answer (score 1):

Just want to remind it is `contentComponent: SidebarScreen`. Check with this if it is working or not :).

Comment: I feel like I am stupid , I have been fixing the errors since 4 hours

Comment: yeah thanks , I am learning react native and new so don't know much